# ActionBarCompat - On draw open/closed not being called?

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.drawer_list_item, DrawTitles));
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
    public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
        actionBar.setTitle("fd");
        invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
    }

    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
        Log.e("KFF", "Draw Open");
        String mystring = "reewr";
        SpannableString s = new SpannableString(mystring);
        s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(MainActivity.this, "cubano"), 0, s.length(),
        Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        actionBar.setTitle(s);
        invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
    }
};
```

No matter what i seem to try, the `onDrawerOpened` or the `Closed` are not being called, despite everything working as expected, including the action bar toggle icon and all functionality.

Comment: Still looking for help on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved.

Seems as though it was the trivial matter of :

```
 mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
```

before i'd setup the actual DrawerToggle, it was initializing and not throwing any errors because the variable is the right type, just simply null.

Something to keep an eye on.

Answer (score 0):

You must use **supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()** instead of  **invalidateOptionsMenu()**.

[This post by Gabriele Mariotti help you to use **ActionBarCompat with the NavigationDrawer**](http://gmariotti.blogspot.com/2013/07/actionbarcompat-and-navigationdrawer.html)

And be careful to not lose code ;)